# how to ignore first and last words using SOUNDEX mssql?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to find all possible words using SOUNDEX.
For example:
I have the table (users) with one field (name):
Users have next view

```
|ID|Name |
|1 |Maria     |
|2 |Ana Maria |
|3 |Maria Ana |
```

if I use Like, I have:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like '%Maria%'
```

As result I got

```
1.Maria     
2.Ana Maria
3.Maria Ana
```

But if I use SOUNDEX

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('Maria')
```

> I got the only two names (Maria and Maria Ana)

I need get result such as when I use like

Comment: "name has 3 rows: "first name, name, last name" . . . I don't get the data structure.  Please edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why do you need to use `SOUNDEX`?

Comment: Sorry, Edited. I use SOUNDEX because I need ignore chars in different languages. for example A and Ă

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE SOUNDEX('Maria') = SOUNDEX('Maria').... This should return the number of records in your table.

Comment: thanks, fixed. Should be  SELECT * FROM users WHERE SOUNDEX(name) = SOUNDEX('Maria')